# Add metadata to method in Typescript

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I have a class in Typescript, in which I need to mark a number of methods as to whether they can be run on the server, the client, or both. I was going to use a decorator, so I would be able to mark the relevant methods with:

```js
class Game {
  @serverAction
  getRandomNumber(): number { return 4; }

  @clientAction
  pass() { }
}
```

etc. Wrapping the value in the decorator gets me some of the way, but I still need to be able to identify from outside the method (and potentially outside the class) which decorators are given to method.

How can I make those decorators accessible?

My first attempt was to include a static dictionary in the class which the decorator adds to, but it will cause issues - as I expect the class to be inherited from multiple times. My second attempt was to add it to the PropertyDescriptor in the decorator method as:

```js
export function clientAction(target: Game, propertyKey: string, descriptor: any) {
    descriptor.custom = "Test"
}
```

but when I attempted to access it with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(testGame.act, 'custom')` (where `testGame` inherited from `game` and `act` was a method decorated with `clientAction`), it returned undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the property descriptor cannot be used to keep extra data other than what it is providing, making it immutable. I would suggest using typescripts' [`reflect-meta`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) which is for this specific case, adding meta data to decorated properties. You can read more on it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) and its [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata).

Here is a case example for its use:

Say you want to mark your decorators as you say so that you can reference the data
in another place at say a later stage for instance, first you would need to write the function that will add the data.

```
// you add the args that will be needed in the function
export function name(data: any) {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    Reflect.defineMetadata(
      // this here is to reference the data later when we retrieve it.
      propertyKey,
      {
        // we put this spread operator in case you have decorated already, so
        // we dont want to lose the old data
        ...Reflect.getMetadata(propertyKey, target),
        // then we append whatever else we need
        name: data,
      },
      target,
    );
    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

That said we can then define a class with some method and decorate it

```
class Name {
  start = 'Hello';

  @name('John Doe')
  display() {
    console.log(this.start);
  }
}
```

So we have done the above, say now we would like to append the decorated string
to the `start` property so that when it prints, it adds the `string`
in the decorator aswell.

```
// so first we get an instance of the class
const a = new Name();

// then we have the get the data

// this will get all the keys that have meta data, which will be 'display'
const keys = Reflect.getMetadataKeys(a);
// then we loop through to get that keys data,
keys.forEach((k) => {
  const data = Reflect.getMetadata(k, a);
  // now we have the meta data so we can append it.

  a.start = `${a.start} ${data.name}`;
});

// and finally, we can call display
a.display(); // 'Hello John Doe'
```

This is a very useful construct provided by typescript, although experimental.